# remove/hide element from post.body in blogger

Tags: javascript, css

how to remove or hide some element content from post body in blogger ?

example picture : [example picture](http://prntscr.com/20cpxp) (red= should be removed)

example site(footer post) : [example site](http://www.every-thing-tech.co.uk/2013/10/either-obama-knew-about-nsa-spying-on.html)

thank's for your answer

Comment: More information is needed.

How do you want this element removed?

Because, honestly, this question could be answered by saying "Delete the content in your code editor"

Comment: @joel, you are right, the element can be removed by editing the post in blogger, but I want to know whether these elements can be hidden with javascript / css in html editor blogger. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Various techniques can be implemented. A few.

With CSS: `your-element{display:none;}`

With Javascript: `var elem = document.getElementById(your-element);elem.style.display = "none";`

With jQuery: `$(your-element).css("display","none")` or `$(your-element).hide()` or etc...